# simple select query very slow

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I use as a cache and using this function

```
def read_cache(table):
    if not table.isidentifier(): # <- my version of sqli protection used to allow for user to provide table and column names
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid table name '{table}'")
    for record in cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table};"):
        yield {**record}
```

a call `list(read_cache('some_values'))` takes forever (nearly a minute) to return, yet when I run the query against the db itself (as in `cur.execute('select * from some_values;').fetchall()` or `[r for r in cur.execute('select * from some_values;')]`) it returns immediately.

The table in question has 40k rows, 2 columns each

What can I do to find the issue or speed it up?

**EDIT:** I think I found the issue, the speed issue only occurs in an interpreter that has some `threading.Thread` running... wonder if the issue is GIL related... will have to see what to do about it...

Comment: Why are you doing this as a generator instead of just returning `.fetchall()`?

Comment: I don't want all consumers growing memory, only who needs all at once will fetch all but the rest can iterate one by one without leaking ram

Comment: If it only happens when threading, it sounds like it's due to locking around the generator or database connection.

Comment: looks like I will need to expedite my learning of asyncio...